# include GLUT in qt project with cmake

Tags: macos, opengl, cmake

I'm trying to do a cmake project with opengl and qt.

this is the cmake where I include opengl:

```
# opengl
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
set(OPENGL_LIBS ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
```

And it found them, this is a part of cmake output:

```
-- Found OpenGL: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework  
-- Found GLUT: -framework GLUT
```

And I can include OpenGL with this:

```
#include <QtOpenGL>
```

with this it finds correctly gl* `glGetString(GL_VENDOR)` or `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` and they works.

BUT I'm not able to include GLUT includes.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.4, Qt 4.8, QtCreator 2.7.1 and Opengl 2.1

Please note that the same cmake file under Ubuntu 12.04 let me include `GL/gl.h` and `GL/glut.h` correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> BUT I'm not able to include GLUT includes.

Why would you want to use GLUT when you're already using Qt?

GLUT is a framework for window creation and event loop processing.
Qt is a framework for window creation and event loop processing.

You can't (well, should not) have two framework within the same program doing the exact same thing (unless you're interested in seeing them fighting some battle over the same resources).

Comment: i'd like to use gluOrtho2D

Comment: @nkint: Well, that's part of GLU, not GLUT (note the missing T). However gluOrtho2D is probably the most redundant function ever; Just use *glOrtho* with -1 for the near and +1 for the far clip distance. This is *exactly* what gluOrtho2D does (calling `glOrtho(…, -1, 1)`).

Answer (score 0):

On OSX you need to include `GLUT/glut.h`, so write something like that in your code:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
    #include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
    #include <GL/glut.h>
#endif
```